# Conditional order by case statement error : String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table valued function where I am trying to add a conditional case order by statement with a bit value. This is in Sql Server 2012. I keep running into the same error trying to add the case statement.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[myFunction] 
(
     @user varchar(30)
    ,@double_entry_flag bit
)
...
begin 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @double_entry_flag = 1 
THEN total_unique_groupcount WHEN @double_entry_flag = 0 
THEN unique_groupcount END DESC
end;
```

keep getting error

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 4
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

But when I switch my order by statement back to normal again i.e.

```
ORDER BY total_unique_groupcount DESC
```

It works fine, there's something about the Syntax or the Case statement it doesn't like. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Try putting the case statement in a column and assigning it a name, and do the ordering by column name, just to try it out!

Comment: What data types are `total_unique_groupcount` and `unique_groupcount`? I bet they are different.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Is the column declared INT or is it calculated?

Comment: Hmm in table designs they are set as INT data type column, one has allow NULLS and the other doesn't tho. Does that matter ?

Comment: But even when I tried the same column in both case conditions I still get the other as well

Comment: I have a feeling it's not going into any CASE statement, so I am just going ORDER BY and then nothing ?

Comment: Have you tried @MiNT's advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @double_entry_flag = 1 THEN total_unique_groupcount END DESC,
CASE WHEN @double_entry_flag = 0 THEN unique_groupcount  END DESC
```

Comment: Tried that got Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 4
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.